# Поле типа HashMap в GraphQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql

Я добавляю функционал к `API` на GraphQL и в запросе нужно передавать поле, в котором находится структура следующего вида:

```
"services": {
    "29bd525c-c6a1-44ad-a993-06894df2154d": { "totalSumInKops": 10000 },
    "4723ebf6-a6ac-4fc6-8148-a94e7819c108": { "totalSumInKops": 5000 }
}
```

Эта структура парсится как `HashMap`:

```
@Override
public Set<Service> convert(Map<String, Map<String, Long>> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().map(stringMapEntry -> {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.setTotalSumInKops(stringMapEntry.getValue().get("totalSumInKops"));
        // service.setInvoice();
        service.setServiceUid(UUID.fromString(stringMapEntry.getKey()));
        return service;
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Но я не знаю, как определить тип этого поля в схеме GraphQL. Сейчас я написал вот что:

```
input ServiceEntryInput {
    totalSumInKops: Long
}

input ServiceInput {
    serviceUid: UUID
    serviceEntry: ServiceEntryInput
}

input UpdateInvoiceInput {
    services: [ServiceInput]
}
```

И такая схема не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно определить тип этого поля.

Comment: UUID  - такого базового типа нет в GraphQL

Comment: или в джаве он приводится к ID?

Comment: @Сергей Коновалов, это у нас собственный скаляр.

Answer (score 0):

Есть дополнительная библиотека для `GraphQL Java`: [GraphQL Java Extended Scalars](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
    <version>2019-08-31T02-34-04-3decba9</version>
</dependency>
```

В схеме нужно добавить скаляр `Object`, например так:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  getEntity: Object
}

scalar Object
```

Далее зарегистрировать этот скаляр в сервисе перед инициализацией объекта `GraphQL` вместе с прочими фетчерами `DataFetcher`:

```java
RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring = RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
    .type("Query", typeWiring -> typeWiring
        .dataFetcher("getEntity", entityFetcher.getEntity()))
    .scalar(ExtendedScalars.Object)
    .build();
```

Класс `dto` в таком случае вообще не нужен, а фетчер может возвращать всё, что угодно, например:

```java
@Component
public class EntityFetcher {
    public DataFetcher<Object> getEntity() {
        return environment -> {
            List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
            objects.add(1);
            objects.add("string");
            objects.add(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            return objects;
        };
    }
}
```